# Wait for Single Instance occurrences to complete before proceeding to next line VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multiple-instances

Currently, I'm using the 'make app single instance'(MyApplication_StartupNextInstance event) in VB (.net framework win forms) to pass command line arguments from multiple instances to the main form. I'm adding this to a list of string and then passing this list to the next function/ sub. The list captures all the arguments if I add a message box just before calling the next function but then when there's no msgbox, not all the arguments are captured.

I've tired using timers/delays which is a hit and a miss. Tried using timed msgbox that disapper after couple secs, which is the same.
How can I make it wait till all the instances have run and then proceed to the next line of code?

```
'ApplicationEvents.vb
 Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance

            Dim f = Application.MainForm

            If f.GetType Is GetType(my_app_name) Then
                CType(f, my_app_name).NewArgumentsReceived(e.CommandLine(0)) 
            End If

        End Sub


'my app has the below codes

Public Sub NewArgumentsReceived(args As String)
        mylist.Add(args)
      

End Sub


Private Sub SomeForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

mylist.Add(arg) 'arg is for main form 'args' is for instances

'this is where I want to wait until all the other instances have completed

Anotherfunction(mylist)

End Sub
```

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make sense. The initial instance doesn't know anything about the subsequent instances until they connect to it, so how is it supposed to know when there are no more instances to connect? That `StartupNextInstance` event can be raised at any time so should the initial instance wait forever, just in case another instance starts up?

Comment: Basically, you should restructure your code so that the main form can receive commandline arguments from a new instance at any time. For instance, lets say that the main form was an MDI parent and it opened text files in child forms. If the initial instance received the path of a file as an argument then it would open one child form containing that file. Each time the `StartupNextInstance` event was raised, you'd open a new child form in the initial instance for the file provided as an argument. That one new child form should be able to be opened at any time.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments, the `StartupNextInstance` event can be raised any time so you should design your app to react to it at any time. The initial instance has no idea how many subsequent instances there will be or when they will start so it should simply react to them one at a time, whenever they occur. Here's an example of a single instance application where the main form is an MDI parent and the commandline arguments are text file paths that each get opened in a child window.

Child form:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class ChildForm

    Public Property FilePath As String

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Parent form:

```vb
Public Class ParentForm

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

        If args.Length > 1 Then
            LoadChildForm(args(1))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadChildForm(filePath As String)
        Dim child As New ChildForm With {.MdiParent = Me,
                                         .FilePath = filePath}

        child.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Application events:

```vb
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
            Dim args = e.CommandLine

            If args.Count > 0 Then
                DirectCast(MainForm, ParentForm).LoadChildForm(args(0))
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

In this case, the initial instance doesn't wait for anything. It just goes ahead and does what it does with its own commandline argument. It has no idea if there will be any subsequent instances or, if there are, how many there will be and when they will start, so it would have no idea what it was waiting for. Any time another instance is started, the initial instance reacts then, using the commandline argument provided.